# Sending XML Interface Request via socket in Delphi

Tags: xml, api, sockets, delphi, tcp

I am trying to replicate my C# socket code into Delphi, but I am having difficulties getting any response back from routines I tried.

I tried using Indy's `TIdTCPClient` component, but I am not getting anything back until it times out.

I would like to recreate the following C# code in Delphi:

```cs
public static string SendXML(String xmlMessage, int cashbackAmount, bool jumpOut = false)
{
    connection:
    try
    {
        string messageToSend = xmlMessage;
        String responseStringData = "";
        // String responseString = "";
        int headerOffset = 2;
        var length = messageToSend.Length;
        byte[] sendbytes = new byte[length + 2];
        byte[] responsebytes = new byte[1024 * 10];
        int remainder = 0;
        var bytesRec = 0;
        if (length < 65535)
        {
            sendbytes[0] = Convert.ToByte(Math.DivRem(length, 256, out remainder));
            sendbytes[1] = Convert.ToByte(remainder);
        }
        else
        {
            headerOffset = 6;
            sendbytes[0] = 0xFF;
            sendbytes[1] = 0xFF;

            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
            Array.Reverse(intBytes);
            byte[] result = intBytes;
            Array.Copy(result, 0, sendbytes, 2, 4);
        }

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server
            // Get Host IP Address that is used to establish a connection
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IP : 127.0.0.1
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses
            // var connectionDetails = new Dictionary<String, String> { { "Host", HostName }, { "Port", Port.ToString() } };
            // Console.WriteLine("Attempting socket connection {0}", connectionDetails);
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 23001);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            Socket s = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to Remote EndPoint
            s.Connect(remoteEP);
            s.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Milliseconds;
            s.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Milliseconds;

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageToSend);
            Array.Copy(msg, 0, sendbytes, headerOffset, msg.Length);
            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = s.Send(sendbytes);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            bool isEvent = true;
            bool didContainEvent = false;
            bool wasCashbackEvent = false;
            bytesRec = 0;
            // since we are still connected, we can receive quite a few event responses and/or callbacks
            // we cannot close this IP connection until all data has come back to us, else this will cause issues
            // as for callbacks, they require a response, in this case we have to keep the IP connection open until
            // we have replied with a callback message
            while (isEvent)
            {
                bytesRec = s.Receive(responsebytes);

                responseStringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responsebytes, 0, bytesRec);
                responseStringData = responseStringData.Substring(2, responseStringData.Length - 2);
                responseStringData = responseStringData.Replace("\0?", "");
                Console.WriteLine("Data Received = {0}", responseStringData);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                isEvent = responseStringData.Contains("Esp:Event") | responseStringData.Contains("Esp:Callback");
                if (isEvent)
                {
                    if (jumpOut)
                    {
                        return responseStringData;
                    }
                    didContainEvent = true;
                    if (!responseStringData.Contains("Esp:Callback"))
                        continue;
                    wasCashbackEvent = true;
                    // Adding Cashback Callback Response Message
                    string cashbackMessage = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Esp:Interface Version=\"1.0\" xmlns:Esp=\"http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/\"><Esp:Callback TerminalId=\"TR000002\" EventId=\"DATA_REQUIRED\" ResponseData=\"{cashbackAmount}\" /></Esp:Interface>";
                    // Sending the cashback message with cashback amount to the callback
                    MessageBox.Show(responseStringData);
                    SendXML(cashbackMessage, 0, jumpOut: true);
                    // Encode the cashback data string into a byte array.
                    byte[] cashMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cashbackMessage);
                    Array.Copy(cashMsg, 0, sendbytes, headerOffset, cashMsg.Length);
                    // Send the data through the socket.
                    s.Send(sendbytes);
                }
                // Return the response 
                return responseStringData;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // txtDisplayMessage.Text = "Failed to connect to socket...";
            return responseStringData;
            // goto connection;
        }
        return responseStringData;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // txtDisplayMessage.Text = "Failed to connect to socket...";
        goto connection;
        // return responseStringData;
    }
    // string responseString = null;
    // return responseStringData;
}
```

**My Delphi code:**

```pascal
function TfrmEFT000.SendXML(xXMLMessage :String; xCashbackAmount :Integer = 0; wJumpOut :Boolean = False): string;
label Connection;
var
  wResponseStringData                                     :String;
  wHeaderOffset, wLength, wRemainder, wByteInt            :Word;
  wBytesRec, wBytesSent                                   :Integer;
  wSendBytes, wResponseBytes, wMsg, wResult               :TIdBytes;
  wIPAddress                                              :TIPAddress;
  //wRemoteEP                                               :PIPE_WAIT=
  wHost : PHostEnt;
  ipAddr : array of TIPAddress;

  wIsEvent, wDidContainEvent, wWasCashbackEvent           :Boolean;
begin

  try
    wHeaderOffset := 2;
    wLength       := Length(xXMLMessage);

    SetLength(wSendBytes, wLength+2);
    SetLength(wResponseBytes, 1024 * 10);
    wRemainder := 0;
    wBytesRec  := 0;

    DivMod(wLength, 264, wByteInt, wRemainder);

    if (wLength < 65535) then
    begin
      wSendBytes[0] := Byte(wByteInt);
      wSendBytes[1] := Byte(wRemainder);
    end
    else
    begin
      wHeaderOffset := 6;
      wSendBytes[0] := $FF;
      wSendBytes[1] := $FF;

//    wIntBytes := BitConverter.GetBytes(wLength);
//    Array.Reverse(wIntBytes);
//    byte[] result = wIntBytes;
//    Array.Copy(result, 0, sendbytes, 2, 4);

    end;

    TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
    try

      wMsg := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetBytes(xXMLMessage);

      Assert(Length(wMsg)<=Length(wSendBytes));
      Move(wMsg[0], wSendBytes[2], Length(wMsg));

      TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(wSendBytes,Length(wSendBytes),2);
      TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;

      // Receive the response from the remote device.
      wIsEvent          := True;
      wDidContainEvent  := False;
      wWasCashbackEvent := False;

      while wIsEvent do begin

        Connection:

        TCPClient.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(255);
        wResponseStringData := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLnWait(30000,IndyTextEncoding_ASCII);

        if (not TCPClient.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty) then
          wResponseStringData := TCPClient.Socket.InputBufferAsString(IndyTextEncoding_ASCII);

        if wResponseStringData = '' then begin
          goto Connection;
        end;

        //TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(wResponseBytes, wBytesRec);

        wResponseStringData := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetString(wResponseBytes,0,wBytesRec);
        wResponseStringData := wResponseStringData.Substring(2, wResponseStringData.Length - 2);
        wResponseStringData := wResponseStringData.Replace('\0?', '');
        LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, 'Data Received = {0}');
        LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, wResponseStringData);
        LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, '');
        LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, '');

      end;

    except
      on E:Exception do begin
        LogMessage(lmtError, ldIn, E.Message);
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferCancel;
      LogMessage(lmtError, ldIn, E.Message);
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
      //goto Connection;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues with your Delphi code:

- you are reusing a single TCP connection across multiple calls, whereas the C# code creates a new TCP connection per call, and even per each iteration of the outer loop.
- your code is assuming that `wLength` is always < 65535. You are not allowing for larger messages. If `wLength` ever happens to be >= 65535, you are not copying `wLength` into `wSendBytes` at all, or copying `wMsg` into the correct offset of `wSendBytes`.  So `wSendBytes` will be corrupted.
- you are not sending all of the bytes that you have put into `wSendBytes`.  You are skipping the first 2 bytes. This statement:

  `TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(wSendBytes,Length(wSendBytes),2);`

  needs be changed to this instead:

  `TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(wSendBytes);`
- there is no need to call `IOHandler.WriteBuffer(Open|Close|Cancel)` since you are making only 1 `IOHandler.Write()` call in between them, so no need to buffer the data.
- you are not handling the possibility of `IOHandler.ReadLnWait()` timing out, the same way the C# code handles `s.Receive()` timing out.  Also, there is no indication in the C# code that `IOHandler.ReadLnWait()` is even the correct method to use on the Delphi code.  The C# code is reading arbitrary bytes, not line-based text data.
- for that matter, assuming the response data is XML, you should be reading from the socket until the last closing tag of the XML document is received, THEN process the response (a push-based XML parser works best for this. You can push arbitrary bytes into it, and it will give you events for fully parsed XML elements).  Both your C# and Delphi codes are assuming the entire XML document will be present in a single read of the socket, but that is simply not how TCP works.
- You are overwriting `wResponseStringData` after receiving it, but before processing it.  First, you receive it with `IOHandler.ReadLnWait()`, but then you receive it again from `IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetString(wResponseBytes)`, even though you have commented out the code that reads bytes into `wResponseBytes`.  So, `wResponseStringData` ends up being empty every time you process it.
- you are not responding to any received events at all, like the C# code does (also, FYI, the C# code is sending the `cashbackMessage` twice, each on separate TCP connections, which seems odd. But more importantly, it is not adjusting the header of `sendbytes` to specify the correct length of `cashbackMessage`).

That being said, I would translate the C# code into Delphi+Indy more like the following instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal, IdStack, IdExceptionCore, IdTCPClient, SysUtils;
  
function SendXML(const xmlMessage: String; cashbackAmount: Integer; jumpOut: Boolean = False): String;
var
  responseStringData: String;
  responsebytes: TIdBytes;
  bytesRec: Integer;
  client: TIdTCPClient;
  isEvent: Boolean;
  didContainEvent: Boolean;
  wasCashbackEvent: Boolean;
  cashbackMessage: String;

  function EncodeMessage(const AMsg: String): TIdBytes;
  var
    length: Integer;
    headerOffset: Integer;
  begin
    length := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetByteCount(AMsg);
    if length < 65535 then
    begin
      SetLength(Result, length + 2);
      CopyTIdUInt16(GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt16(length)), Result, 0);
      headerOffset := 2;
    end
    else
    begin
      SetLength(Result, length + 6);
      Result[0] := $FF;
      Result[1] := $FF;
      CopyTIdUInt32(GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt32(length)), Result, 2);
      headerOffset := 6;
    end;
    CopyTIdString(AMsg, Result, headerOffset, length, IndyTextEncoding_ASCII);
  end;

begin
  SetLength(responsebytes, 1024 * 10);

  // Create a TCP/IP socket.
  client := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  try
    client.Host := 'localhost';
    client.Port := 23001;
    client.ReadTimeout := 30000;

    repeat
      try
        responseStringData := '';
        //responseString := '';

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try
          // Connect to a Remote server
          // WriteLn('Attempting socket connection, Host: ', client.Host, ', Port: ', client.Port);

          // Connect to Remote EndPoint
          client.Connect;
          try
            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            // Send the data through the socket.
            client.IOHandler.Write(EncodeMessage(xmlMessage));

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            isEvent := True;
            didContainEvent := False;
            wasCashbackEvent := False;

            // since we are still connected, we can receive quite a few event responses and/or callbacks
            // we cannot close this IP connection until all data has come back to us, else this will cause issues
            // as for callbacks, they require a response, in this case we have to keep the IP connection open until
            // we have replied with a callback message
            repeat
              client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(s.ReadTimeout);
              client.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
              if client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then EIdReadTimeout.Create('');

              bytesRec := IndyMin(client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, Length(responsebytes));
              if bytesRec > 0 then begin
                client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(responsebytes, bytesRec, False);
              end;

              responseStringData := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetString(responsebytes, 0, bytesRec);
              responseStringData := Copy(responseStringData, 2, Length(responseStringData));
              responseStringData := StringReplace(responseStringData, #0'?', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

              WriteLn('Data Received = ', responseStringData);
              WriteLn;
              WriteLn;

              isEvent := (Pos('Esp:Event', responseStringData) <> 0) or (Pos('Esp:Callback', responseStringData) <> 0);
              if isEvent and (not jumpOut) then
              begin
                didContainEvent := True;
                if Pos('Esp:Callback', responseStringData) = 0 then
                  Continue;
                wasCashbackEvent := True;

                // Adding Cashback Callback Response Message
                cashbackMessage := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/"><Esp:Callback TerminalId="TR000002" EventId="DATA_REQUIRED" ResponseData="' + IntToStr(cashbackAmount) + '" /></Esp:Interface>';
                // Sending the cashback message with cashback amount to the callback
                ShowMessage(responseStringData);

                //SendXML(cashbackMessage, 0, True);

                // Encode the cashback data string into a byte array.
                // Send the data through the socket.
                client.IOHandler.Write(EncodeMessage(cashbackMessage));
              end;
              // Return the response 
              Result := responseStringData;
              Exit;
            until not isEvent;
          finally
            client.Disconnect;
            if client.IOHandler <> nil then begin
              client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
            end;
          end;
        except
          // txtDisplayMessage.Text := 'Failed to connect to socket...';
          Result := responseStringData;
          Exit;
        end;
        // Continue;
        Result := responseStringData;
        Exit;
      except
        // txtDisplayMessage.Text := 'Failed to connect to socket...';
        Continue;
        // Result := responseStringData;
      end;
    until False;
  finally
    client.Free;
  end;
  // Result := '';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate it. Here's an answer below if anyone ever needs it.

```
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function TfrmEFT000.SendXML(xXMLMessage :String; xCashbackAmount :Integer = 0; xJumpOut :Boolean = False): string;
var
 wRespData, wCBReq                                                 :String;
 wHeaderOffset, wLength, wRemainder, wByteInt                      :Word;
 wBytesRec, wBytesSent                                             :Integer;
 wSendBytes, wResponseBytes, wMsg, wIntBytes, wResult, wCashMsg    :TIdBytes;
 wIsEvent, wDidContainEvent, wWasCashbackEvent                     :Boolean;
begin

 try
  wHeaderOffset := 2;
  wLength       := Length(xXMLMessage);

  SetLength(wSendBytes, wLength+2);
  SetLength(wResponseBytes, 1024 * 10);
  wRemainder := 0;
  wBytesRec  := 0;

  DivMod(wLength, 256, wByteInt, wRemainder);

  if (wLength < 65535) then
   begin
    wSendBytes[0] := Byte(wByteInt);
    wSendBytes[1] := Byte(wRemainder);
   end
  else
   begin
    wHeaderOffset := 6;
    wSendBytes[0] := $FF;
    wSendBytes[1] := $FF;

    wIntBytes := GetBytes(wLength);
    ReverseArray(wIntBytes);
    wResult := wIntBytes;

    CopyTIdBytes(wResult, 0, wSendBytes, 2, 4);
   end;

  try

   // Encode the data string into a byte array.
   wMsg := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetBytes(xXMLMessage);
   CopyTIdBytes(wMsg, 0, wSendBytes, wHeaderOffset, Length(wMsg));

   // Send the data through the socket.
   SendToSocket(wSendBytes);

   wBytesSent := Length(wSendBytes);

   // Receive the response from the remote device.
   wIsEvent          := True;
   wDidContainEvent  := False;
   wWasCashbackEvent := False;
   wBytesRec         := 0;
   // since we are still connected, we can receive quite a few event responses and/or callbacks
   // we cannot close this IP connection until all data has come back to us, else this will cause issues
   // as for callbacks, they require a response, in this case we have to keep the IP connection open until
   // we have replied with a callback message
   while wIsEvent = True do begin

    TCPClient.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);

    wBytesRec := TCPClient.Socket.InputBuffer.Size;

    if (not TCPClient.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty) then begin
     wRespData := TCPClient.Socket.InputBufferAsString(IndyTextEncoding_ASCII);
    end;

    if wRespData = '' then begin
     Next;
     Continue;
    end;

    //wRespData := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetString(wResponseBytes,0,wBytesRec);
    wRespData := wRespData.Substring(2, wRespData.Length - 2);
    wRespData := wRespData.Replace('\0?', '');
    LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, 'Data Received = {0}', memRequest);
    LogMessage(lmtInformation, ldIn, (wRespData), memRequest);

    wIsEvent := wRespData.Contains('Esp:Event') or wRespData.Contains('Esp:Callback');

    if (wIsEvent = True) then begin

     if (xJumpOut = False) then begin
      Result := wRespData;
      Exit;
     end;

     wDidContainEvent := True;

     if not (wRespData.Contains('Esp:Callback')) then begin
      Continue;
     end;

     wWasCashbackEvent := true;
     // Adding Cashback Callback Response Message
     wCBReq := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
     wCBReq := wCBReq + '<Esp:Interface Version="1.0" xmlns:Esp="http://www.mosaicsoftware.com/Postilion/eSocket.POS/">';
     wCBReq := wCBReq + '<Esp:Callback TerminalId="TR000002" EventId="DATA_REQUIRED" ResponseData="{cashbackAmount}" />';
     wCBReq := wCBReq + '</Esp:Interface>';
     // Sending the cashback message with cashback amount to the callback
     ShowMessage(wRespData);
     SendXML(wCBReq, 0, True);
     // Encode the cashback data string into a byte array.
     wCashMsg := IndyTextEncoding_ASCII.GetBytes(wCBReq);
     CopyTIdBytes(wCashMsg, 0, wSendBytes, wHeaderOffset, Length(wCashMsg));
     // Send the data through the socket.
     SendToSocket(wSendBytes);
    end;
    // Return the response
    Result := wRespData;
   end;

  except
   on E:Exception do begin
    TCPClient.Socket.WriteBufferCancel;
    LogMessage(lmtError, ldIn, E.Message, memRequest);
    Exit;
   end;
  end;

 except
  on E: Exception do begin
   TCPClient.Socket.WriteBufferCancel;
   LogMessage(lmtError, ldIn, E.Message, memRequest);
   Exit;
  end;
 end;

end;
```